# Changing the background colour of a class in CSS not working?

Tags: css, class, background-color

I am trying to change the background-color of an h1 class, but any changes I try to make have no effect, this is the code I have written:

```
.entry-title {
background-color: #f0eaca;
}
```

The title appears white instead of beige like everything else: https://apatheticpaper.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/raf-simons/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use !important.

the issue is, it has a style for background. so,

```
    .single .featured-portrait .entry-title, .page .featured-portrait .entry-title
{
background : none repeat scroll 0 0 #f0eaca;
}
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

Your title class seems to be overridden by some media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1359px)
   .single .featured-portrait .entry-title {
      color: white;
   }
}
```

You either need to override it with specificity or !important (not advised):

```
.single .featured-portrait .entry-title {
   color: #f0eaca;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this class is over riding your property

```
.page .featured-portrait .entry-title
{background-color:white;}
```

Instead change it to

```
.page .featured-portrait .entry-title
    {background-color:#f0eaca;}
```

try with `!important` as another option

Answer (score 0):

As i can see currently on your code :

```
h1.entry-title {
    background-color: #f0eaca !important;
}
```

So to update your code, you need to made the same or upper priority on like :

```
h1.entry-title {
    background-color: #123456 !important;
}
```

[You should read this article about priority on css](http://web-profile.com.ua/css/docs/css-styles-priority/)

Comment: Indeed! In this case he used.

Comment: No need to use it. See my answer.